# Frequency Logic

Tags: logic

Person A is present 100% of the time, and person B is present 50% of the time. In relation to eachother, person A consumes 66% of the time and person B consumes 33% of the time. When a person is present, the do a task periodically and alternate when both are present.

ie: Person A goes to a job for 2mo, person B goes to the same job for the 2nd half only being there for 1mo. Every 2 weeks, a task is completed. Person A completes 2 tasks; person B completes 1 task, then the last task is completed by person A (they alternated while both are present).

The conundrum is that person A does 75% of the tasks while he is only present 66% of the time. Why? (compared to 25% of the 33% present person B) Both would consider the work amount equal, but it's really not?

Answer (score 1):

If the task takes $8$ weeks, and $A$ and $B$ are both there for the first $4$ weeks, then $A$ and $B$ each do $2$ weeks' worth of work (they alternate).

Then $A$ does a full $4$ weeks' worth of work when $B$ isn't there.

So, $A$ works $6$ weeks ($75\%$) and $B$ works $2$ weeks ($25\%$).

Comment: in other words, it's because 100% *(100%-50%)+50%*50% = 75%